# Get Multiple Records Within Date Range Between Two Dates

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table :

```
ID    Title  Value   StartDate      EndDate
=========================================
1      t1     10     10-01-2019   15-01-2019
2      t2     20     15-01-2019   20-01-2019
3      t2     20     20-01-2019   25-01-2019
```

If I pass 01-01-2019 and 30-01-2019, I expect the following has output.

Output Expected:

```
1      t1     10     10-01-2019   15-01-2019
2      t2     20     15-01-2019   20-01-2019
3      t2     20     20-01-2019   25-01-2019
```

Comment: There is no difference between the content of your table and the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the  `overlaps` operator:

```
select *
from the_table
where (startdate, enddate) overlaps (date '2019-01-01', date '2019-01-30');
```

The `overlaps` operator works as the name suggest. It would e.g. include a start/end like 2019-01-20/2019-02-05 (because that range "overlaps" with the one specified)

If your input needs to be contained completely in the range defined by startdate/enddate, a query using a [date range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) and the "contains" operator would be better.

```
select *
from the_table
where daterange(startdate, enddate, '()') <@ daterange(date '2019-01-01', date '2019-01-30', '()');
```

Or you can use a simple lower than bigger than/lower than condition:

```
select *
from the_table
where startdate >= date '2019-01-01'
  and enddate <= date '2019-01-30';
```

Online example (with more data): https://rextester.com/ALJSJE59375

Comment: It working. you are great!!. saved my day....